# Vue | How to change port number to 80 for web?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

So I'm trying to deploy my vue app and for testing I want to switch my port 80 so I can see links without the :8080 extension. When I do this I get a fatal error

```
> node build/dev-server.js

> Starting dev server...
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1343:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1401:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1485:7)
    at Function.listen (/Users/Maceto/Desktop/sts/StsSnag/client/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Maceto/Desktop/sts/StsSnag/client/build/dev-server.js:85:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@1.0.0 start: `node build/dev-server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Maceto/.npm/_logs/2019-02-28T21_07_27_188Z-debug.log
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong I changed the port in the config file but I get this. This also only happens on port 80.

Comment: The first 1024 ports can only be used with root privileges.  See: [Why are the first 1024 ports restricted to the root user only?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16564/167420).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to either do

```
sudo node build/dev-server.js
```

or

```
sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /path/to/nodejs
```

and then you'll be able to do it without sudo

Comment: This works perfectly thank you. However I'm trying to run this same code on a aws Ec2 server and when i run the same command it doesn't work. Its saying node command was not found for sudo is there a way to allow this?

Comment: if it's not finding it for sudo then chances are it's not in sudo's path, is you run `sudo visudo` you should see the path that sudo uses somewhere in the screen that comes up